# INDEX MATCH with Nested IF Statements

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here is my statement with just one `IF` Statement:

```
=IF(AF2="Consultant",IF(C2=INDEX(JIRA!F:F,MATCH('RFO Checks'!M2,JIRA!A:A,0)),1,0),"N/A")
```

This works great, but now I need to add two more `IF` Statements.

`AF2` will either contain `"Consultant"`, `"Retailer"`, or `"PC"`.

Each one will be directed to a different price column:

- for `"Consultant"` it's `JIRA!F:F`
- for `"Retailer"` it's `JIRA!D:D`
- for `"PC"`, it's `JIRA!E:E`.

I've been wracking my brain for two days now and haven't gotten no where.

Suggestions?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Thank you GalAbra for your help.. it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CHOOSE()

```
=IFERROR(--(C2=INDEX(CHOOSE(MATCH(AF2,{"Consultant", "Retailer", "PC"},0),JIRA!F:F,JIRA!D:D,JIRA!E:E),MATCH('RFO Checks'!M2,JIRA!A:A,0))),"N/A")
```

Answer (score 1):

Aaron,

I have provided you the high level structure for the change of logic.

If this is what you want, then you can substitute the  phrases with the appropriate logic.

```
=IF(AF2="Consultant",
    IF(C2=INDEX(JIRA!F:F,MATCH('RFO Checks'!M2,JIRA!A:A,0)),1,0),
    IF(AF2="Retailer",
        <insert_logic_for_retailer>,
        IF(AF2="PC",<insert_logic_for_PC>,"N/A")
      )
   )
```

Logic for Consultant -

```
    IF(C2=INDEX(JIRA!F:F,MATCH('RFO Checks'!M2,JIRA!A:A,0)),1,0)
```

Logic for Retailer, use this to replace -

```
    IF(C2=INDEX(JIRA!D:D,MATCH('RFO Checks'!M2,JIRA!A:A,0)),1,0)
```

Logic for PC, use this to replace -

```
    IF(C2=INDEX(JIRA!E:E,MATCH('RFO Checks'!M2,JIRA!A:A,0)),1,0)
```

Let me know in case you still have any issues!

Comment: In using 'IF' I would flip the IF inside the `INDEX`: `=INDEX(IF(AF2="Consultant",JIRA!F:F,IF(AF2="Retailer",JIRA!D:D,...))),MATCH...)`  It would eliminate the duplicate typing and shorten the formula.

Comment: @ScottCraner, not only your solutions are amazing, you yourself are a very nice person too. Thanks for your insights and may god bless you!

Comment: You are too kind.  I am just here to help.

Comment: Thank you for all your help!